# what lifecycle methods are called on a reusable element in a recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have a RecyclerView to which I pass text and want to understand the following: if lineCount > 3, then I show the expand button, set the ellipsize to end state and make maxLines = 3.

To do this I use a textView listener, something like this. I'm setting currentLineCount = textView.lineCount and causing other states to be set inside the listener such as maxLines etc

```
fun View.afterLayoutConfiguration(func: () -> Unit) {
     viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
         override fun onGlobalLayout() {
             viewTreeObserver?.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
             func()
         }
     })
}
```

However, I'm running into a problem because the RecyclerView is reusing items and listening causes the state of the old views to be applied to new items when scrolling.

I need help understanding how to solve this case, because I haven’t found how to calculate the number of lines in a textview.

Comment: Reading your question I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if you asking which method will be called for `RecyclerView` reusing item then `onBindViewHolder` method in Adapter will trigger everytime even for reusing item. Hope you find your solution or for more suggestions please share your adapter. It would be better to suggest any solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal was to find out whether my text was more than 3 lines or not. if yes, make the button visible and set the maximum number of lines to 3. The question was to understand the life cycle and install and remove the listener in time, but the solution with the listener for the number of lines is incorrect because the recyclerView carries bugs

I ended up going down a different path. I decided to set the attributes `android:ellipsize="end"`, `android:maxLines="3"`
and then

```
Text.post {
  val isEllipsizeApplied = TextUtils.equals(text, Text.layout.text).not()
  tvExpand.visibility = if (isEllipsizeApplied || isExpanded) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

I hope this helps someone)